# How to return indexedDB query result out of event handler?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, closures, indexeddb

I have to return query result from indexedDB, but the result is only available in `onsuccess` event handler.

```
1  function listPeople(){
     ...
4    var open = indexedDB.open("AccordionDatabase",1),
5        res;
6
7    open.onsuccess = function(){
8        var db = open.result;
9        var transaction = db.transaction("PeopleStore", "readwrite");
10        var store = transaction.objectStore("PeopleStore");
11        var request = store.getAll();
12        request.onsuccess = function(event){
13            res = event.target.result;
14            console.log(res);
15        };
16
17        // Close the db when the transaction is done
18        transaction.oncomplete = function() {
19            db.close();
20        };
21
22    };
23    return res;
24 }
```

The output of the function call shows `undefined`, though console prints the result array. Please guide me how to use the variable as output.

Comment: You don't return from the handler, you handle the results in the `onsuccess` handler, or call an external function to handle results.

Comment: If so, couldn't we use indexedDB query results in those cases? Is it only for function parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your last comment. The request is asynchronous, returning from `listPeople` will happen before the results are defined. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323

Comment: I want to ask if there is no way to return results from indexedDB directly.

Comment: No, there's no way to do that.

Comment: @Teemu, Thank you for your kind help. Then, indexedDB must have very limited usages, I guess. I need to migrate from indexedDB to other solution, such as localStorage.

Comment: It is not limited, it's just asynchronous, which needs a bit different logic to handle with. That is something worth of learning, you will bump into it in the future very often.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154921/discussion-between-miron-and-teemu).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can either use this project: https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb

or you need to wrap indexedDB operation into a promise and thus make the list people asynchronous:

```
function listPeople() {
// ...
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var open = indexedDB.open("AccordionDatabase",1),
    open.onsuccess = function() {
      var db = open.result;
      var transaction = db.transaction("PeopleStore", "readwrite");
      var store = transaction.objectStore("PeopleStore");
      var request = store.getAll();
      request.onsuccess = function(event){
        resolve(event.target.result);
      };

      request.onerror = function(event) { reject(event) }

      // Close the db when the transaction is done
      transaction.oncomplete = function() {
        db.close();
      };
      transaction.onerror = function(event) { reject(event) }
    };
    open.onerror = function(event) { reject(event) }
  })
}

// usage:
function doWorkWithListedPeople(people) {
  // ...
}

function handleErrorsDuringIndexedDbRequest(event) {
  // ...
}

listPeople().then(doWorkWithListedPeople).catch(handleErrorsDuringIndexedDbRequest)

// or also
listPeople().then(function(people) { doWorkWithListedPeople(people) })
```

The thing is, you create a promise that represents work that will be eventually done. You can tell JS that eventually, when the promise has been resolved (success), you want to `then` to work with anything that has been passed to `resolve`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function for details

---

EDIT

furthermore, if you don't like thens, you can make do with async await, which unwraps promises. Just beware, you can only use await keyword from within async function:

```
async function doStuff() {
  try {
    var people = await listPeople()
    // now you can work with ppl
  }
  catch (err) {
    // handle listPeople errors here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This is what I am finding for. And thanks `Javascript` for providing `Promise`.

Answer (score -3):

indexedDB functions are nearly all asynchronous. You should be familiar with writing asynchronous Javascript before using indexedDB.

Comment: Don't you know either? This answer is too general. Actually, anyone can answer this way.

Comment: It is the most basic answer you are probably going to get without repeating answers already provided to the same question